# Javascript image preloading, I'm doing something wrong

Tags: javascript, image, preload

I'm using document.images to load images when a visitor first visits the website. The reason is because I have a few different areas which have rollover images. Before I switch over to using CSS sprites (modifying a lot of work), I'm going to ask here.

So I'm preloading images with this:

```
images = new Array();

if (document.images) {
    images.push(preloadImage("http://website.com/images/myimg.png", 300, 200));
}

function preloadImage(src, x, y) {
    var img = new Image(x, y);
    img.src = src;
    return img;
}
```

And according to Chrome's  "resource" panel, this is working just fine. Even after pressing CTRL+F5, the images listed in the JS are downloaded.

HOWEVER, they are not used. If I hover over an element in one of my three scripts, the image is *downloaded a second time*. Derp?

I assume that when preloading images this way, you're supposed to put that image array to use. I thought the browser would be smart enough to say "Hey, this is the same image, let's use it twice" but apparently not.

So is this correct? Do I need to rewrite my programs to preload images individually? I know it doesn't sound hard, but it's really not designed for that.

Comment: What are the cache settings on the images?

Comment: You don't need to store the created images in an array. Once you set their source attribute, the file is downloaded. You can discard the image object right away. Also, `if (document.images) ...` check makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an answer to your question, but I proprose a different solution. Put all the images you need to preload inside a div that is hidden from the user. I know, I know, this i not as elegant, but it should work just fine. :)

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <img src="http://website.com/images/myimg.png" alt=""/>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: `s/hidden/none`, otherwise +1 since it's a JS-less solution. I've used this strategy before with great success. You just can't mess up something this simple.

Comment: /facepalm, why did I not think of this? Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
    function imgPreload() {
        var imageList = [
            "my/firstimage.png",
            "my/secondimage.jpg",
            "my/thirdimage.png"
        ];
        for (var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++ ) {
            var imageObject = new Image();
            imageObject.src = imageList[i];
        }
    }

    imgPreload();
```

Cheers. Frank